# Issue applying SUPEE-10752 (no errors)

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, ce-1.9.1.0, supee-10570

Trying to apply SUPEE-10752, but I'm having a hard time decoding what it's saying. I don't see any hunks failing, and no files are modified (new or updates to existing). Any idea what the issue could be?

Note: I never installed SUPEE-10570v1.

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-10752_CE_v1.9.1.1_v1-2018-06-11-04-32-08.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Composite/Fieldset/Options.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Datetime.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Wysiwyg/ImagesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/StoreController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract/Backend/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Freemethod.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/OriginShipment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/shipping/ups.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/items/renderer/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Usa.csv
patching file cron.php
patching file js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/.htaccess
patching file lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
```

Comment: Did you installed the **`SUPEE-10570v2`** ?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI I am also facing the same issue. I have install the `SUPEE-10570` but as per your comments didn't found any patch related to `SUPEE-10570v2`. Please let me know where should I found this and need to apply before the `SUPEE-10752` ?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI no, haven't installed any versions of SUPEE-10570.

Comment: @Narayan you can get them from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?icid=topnav) search for **SUPEE-10570** & from the drop-down download **`SUPEE-10570v2`**

Comment: @Narayan If my answer helped in solving problem do Upvote so that it can help others also facing same issue

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI Sure

Answer (score 4):

When applying any patch to the Magento make sure you have applied the previous patch also into it. If it is not applied then may be you can face some error as because many times the new patches are dependent on the older one.

In your case as I understood that you haven't applied the **`SUPEE-10570v1`** but make sure you have applied **`SUPEE-10570v2`** as because I have already told that **make sure you install all the previous patches** & that also in sequense of their release.

The conflicts you are facing are due to the not existance of the previous patch or may be the dependent patch. This issue is can also arise due to the installation of **`SUPEE-10570v1`** so just revert that patch & install the **`SUPEE-10570v2`** as because the **`SUPEE-10570v1`** is causing some conflicts while installing the **`SUPEE-10752`** described by the Magento Tech resource as below.

> NOTE: Conflicts during installation of the patch SUPEE-10752 are
>   caused most often by having version 1 of the previous patch installed
>   (SUPEE-10570v1). Please make sure to remove SUPEE-10570v1 and install
>   SUPEE-10570v2 prior to installation of SUPEE-10752.
>
> refer : [this link for better understanding](https://www.magento.com/security/patches/supee-10752)

To check the previously applied patch & follow the sequence do refer [this link](https://www.magereport.com/)

You can also cross check the file available at below location named **applied.patches.list**

```
Magento_root/app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

To revert the patch run below command

```
sh patch-file-name.sh -R
```

To get the **`SUPEE-10570v2`**  or other patches just go to [this location](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?icid=topnav) & search for the patch **`SUPEE-10570`** & from the drop-down of it choose **`SUPEE-10570v2`** & install this patch only.

You can also get other patches that you haven't installed. Download the patches suits to your magento version (Make sure you are not applying the patch of any other magento version) & apply the same to your magento.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. 
I used this link to resolved AccountController hunk : https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-10752-without-ssh/